# if -statement depending on another column in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to write a if statement that change values based off another column. This is in R

```
dfz <- data.frame(
  Time = c(200, 1000, 500, 800, 1200, 1300, 1500, NA, NA, NA),
  CA = c(rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(2,3),rep(0,3)),
  FO = c(rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(2,3),rep(0,3))
)
```

this is the code for the data. I want change CA to 1 if the time is not NA, keep CA 1 if is 1, if time is NA change to CA 0, keep CA 2 if it is 2.

This is the code I tried.

```
dfz$CA = ifelse(!(is.na(dfz$Time) & dfz$CA == 0), 1,
                ifelse(is.na(dfz$Time) & dfz$CA == 0), 0,
                ifelse(!(is.na(dfz$Time) & dfz$CA == 2),2,
                       ifelse(!(is.na(dfz$Time) & dfz$CA == 1), 1,dfz$CA)))
```

This a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhVCJ.png)

Comment: Could you consider responding to the answer given in your last question? It is more or less a very similar problem and it seems to be the case that you don't understand it.

Comment: Also, your requirement is not really well defined. If e.g. `CA = 2` and `!is.na(Time)`, then it is not clear whether `CA = 2` or `CA = 1` shall be used.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).